# Git - Cloning only creates folder and ends up hanging

Tags: git, github

I have a github account and marked one of the repository as private.  Files were pushed to this repo from MachineA (running Win10) using account UAccount1.

Now, i'm trying to access the private repository from MachineB (running Win11 Home) using account UAccount2. I found the folder is created in MachineB after issuing the clone command.  But none of the files were synched to MachineB.

What is the procedure to get all the files of the given repository?  Is making the visibility to public is the only option ?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: The `git clone` command copies a *repository* (not individual files) to a new, separate repository (that contains the same *commits* as the original) and then, as its final step, *checks out* one commit. The commit that it checks out determines which files you will see in the new repository's working tree. So: which *commit* (by hash ID) are you actually checking out? Which commit did you expect to check out? Figure these out and you'll know what's going on here.

Comment: You mention (in the title) "ends up hanging": that suggests that the clone has not proceeded into its final "check out one commit" step and is still running, and that would explain why there are no files yet. If it *is* hanging, you'll need to debug that: either you have permission to clone and you should get a whole copy, or you don't and you should get an error (and the attempt to clone will give up and remove the empty folder it made to hold the new repository).

Comment: @torek the - warning: could not find UI helper 'GitHub.UI'- is the cause of hanging. I tried pushing from powershell, but instead of locking up (like it did in bash) I got a text menu of ways to authenticate with credentials manager. Using the default, "Web browser", with a browser already authenticated to my Github account did the trick

Comment: That warning is due to a bug in recently released Git Credential Manager versions. Downgrade (back out the bug) or upgrade (if another release is out now) and you'll get past that bug.

Comment: Another release should be available [in the next few hours](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/4165#issuecomment-1361111399).

Comment: This should be fixed in https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/tag/v2.39.0.windows.2

Answer (score 3):

> Is making the visibility to public is the only option ?

No, but you need to confirm GitHub account '`UAccount2`' is declared as a [collaborator](https://docs.github.com/en/account-and-profile/setting-up-and-managing-your-personal-account-on-github/managing-access-to-your-personal-repositories/inviting-collaborators-to-a-personal-repository) of the private repository.

Then a git clone would clone and checkout the files from the default branch of that repository.
Make sure which account is actually used:

- an SSH URL might use an SSH key associated to another account, for instance
- an HTTPS URL might use cached credentials associated to another account.

---

The [OP luckyluke](https://stackoverflow.com/users/840352/luckyluke) adds in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74859513/git-cloning-only-creates-folder-and-ends-up-hanging/74859564#comment132130819_74859564):

> the warning: `could not find UI helper 'GitHub.UI'` is the issue.
>
> I tried pushing from PowerShell, but instead of locking up (like it did in bash), I got a text menu of ways to authenticate with credentials manager.
> Using the default, "`Web browser`", with a browser already authenticated to my Github account did the tric

---

This should be fixed in [Git For Windows v2.39.0.windows.2](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/tag/v2.39.0.windows.2)

> The Git Credential Manager version shipped with Git for Windows v2.39.0 [could not always find its UI helper](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/4165) which was fixed by [upgrading to a fixed version](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/4166).

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I did added a collaborator as told. trying to use the HTTPS url to clone the repository but still i'm getting only the folder and not files under it

Comment: @luckyluke Does a `git ls-remote https://github.com/auser/arepo` returns all the branches for that proivate repository? Can you try a clone using an SSH URL?

Comment: thank you @VonC . the - warning: could not find UI helper 'GitHub.UI'- is the issue. I tried pushing from powershell, but instead of locking up (like it did in bash) I got a text menu of ways to authenticate with credentials manager. Using the default, "Web browser", with a browser already authenticated to my Github account did the trick

Comment: @luckyluke Thank you for your feedback. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: The UI helper thing is some sort of version or build issue with GCM. I'm not sure about the details here, but it started earlier this month and might be fixed by now...

Comment: @torek Yes, possibly related to [issue 4166](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/4166), [PR 4168](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/pull/4168). But also [issue 4165](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/4165) linked to [GCM issue 993](https://github.com/GitCredentialManager/git-credential-manager/issues/993). The latest [Git for Windows snapshot](https://wingit.blob.core.windows.net/files/index.html) should work. A release of Git For windows is [in progress right now](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/4165#issuecomment-1361111399).

Comment: @torek Released: https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/tag/v2.39.0.windows.2

Answer (score 1):

If you are using different devices and different GitHub accounts, you will need to request access to the repository for each account that you want to grant access to.

To do this, you will need to follow these steps:

1. On the first device, log in to the GitHub account that has access to the repository and navigate to the repository.
2. Click on the "Settings" tab for the repository and then click on the "Collaborators" subtab.
3. In the "Collaborators" section, enter the username of the GitHub account that you want to grant access to.
4. Click the "Add collaborator" button to invite the user to the repository.
5. On the second device, log in to the GitHub account that you just invited to the repository and navigate to the repository.
6. You should now have access to the repository on the second device.

Note that the repository owner will need to approve any access requests before the user is granted access to the repository.