# How can I push in Git Bash with warning: could not find UI helper 'GitHub.UI'?

Tags: github, git-bash, git-push

I have:

```bash
$ git push -u origin feature/lesson

warning: could not find UI helper 'GitHub.UI'**
```

I'm told these are my only options. Is this true?

"The issue seems to be with Git Credential Manager v 2.39.0 which is installing along with the git install."

Workaround Fix:
Until a new release is available, below are some workarounds.

- Reinstall git without selecting 'none' on the screen where have option to "choose a Credetial Manager"
- Rollback to version 2.38.x (older releases https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/
- Use GitHub Desktop application

I've done nothing yet. I was hoping not to have to reinstall.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I was hoping not to have to reinstall.

Yet, if you can upgrade to [Git for Windows 2.39.0(2)](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/tag/v2.39.0.windows.2) released yesterday (Dec. 21, 2022), the fix should be included, as I [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74859564/6309).

This was reported in [issue 4165](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/4165).